# Installation failed because the device "oneplus-oneplus_a5010-f95d9d0f" disconnected [Problem]

Tags: android, android-studio, oneplusone

When I try to run my android studio project in the Oneplus device it shows `Installation failed because the device "oneplus-oneplus_a5010-f95d9d0f" disconnected."`

But if I run this command `adb start-server` in the terminal it works fine.

I have tried this command: `adb start-server`.

I want to fix it. Every time it will run without the command that I wrote in the previous section. Is there any permanent solution?

**Problem Snapshot:**

[image]

**After Write `adb start-server` Snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: Try one thing. When you see this error, don't run any command. but re-plug USB cable in device and run your app again. check it is working or not.

Comment: I have tried a lot of time. It shows the same reason.

Comment: have you installed the android adb drivers separately? It could happen due to a conflict in the one that came with android studio and one you installed separately.. Change it to the correct one and it would work..

Comment: Not understand clearly. Can you explain more? @sanjeev